# How to sort output based on a custom created object in Powershell?

Tags: powershell, scripting, ps

I've the following function to get folder sizes, under a given directory.

```
function Get-FolderSize {
      [CmdletBinding()]
      param (
        [Parameter(ValueFromPipeline=$true)]
        [string]$Path
      )
      
      process {
        $folders = Get-ChildItem $Path -Directory
        foreach ($folder in $folders) {
          $size = [Math]::round((Get-ChildItem $folder.FullName -Recurse | Measure-Object -Property Length -Sum).Sum / 1GB, 2)
          $obj = New-Object PSObject -Property @{
            Name = $folder.Name
            Size = $size
          }
          $obj
        }
      }
    };
    $path =  pwd;
    Get-FolderSize -Path $path -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue;
```

The above code gives the following o/p:

```
Name                 Size
----                 ----
getting-started      0.01
Favorites               0
iotedge              0.04
git                  0.12
eclipse-workspace    0.16
Documents            0.09
Desktop                 0
eclipse              0.29
Downloads            1.66
Links                   0
source                  0
Searches                0
workspace            0.16
```

I need to sort the o/p, based on the custom-object 'Size'. Can someone help me out here? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You mean with `Sort-Object`? `Get-FolderSize -Path $path | Sort-Object -Property 'Size'`

Comment: Yes. I tried the same code as above, but didn't get any result whatsoever.

Comment: I tried this works, ```Get-FolderSize -Path 'C:\Temp' -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | Sort-Object Size```

Answer (score 0):

Putting Abraham's comment to answer:

`Sort-Object` command does your job seamlessly

Replace

```
Get-FolderSize -Path $path -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
```

With This:

```
Get-FolderSize -Path $path -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | Sort-Object Size -Descending
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Function Get-FolderSize {
  [CmdletBinding()]
  param (
    [Parameter(ValueFromPipeline=$true)]
    [string]$Path
  )

  process {
    $return= @()
    $folders = Get-ChildItem $Path -Directory
    foreach ($folder in $folders) {
      $size = [Math]::round((Get-ChildItem $folder.FullName -Recurse | Measure-Object -Property Length -Sum).Sum / 1GB, 2)
      $obj = New-Object PSObject -Property @{
        Name = $folder.Name
        Size = $size
      }
      $return += $obj
    }
    $return = $return | Sort-Object -Property Size -Descending
    return $return
  }
}

$path =  "my full path"
Get-FolderSize -Path $path -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
```